# How to import .txt file to SQL Server database with WPF button click event

Tags: c#, sql-server, text-files, openfiledialog

I have a button click event which opens the file dialog, select a .txt file, and display the file path in `TextBox`.

The issue I am having is I am not sure how I can upload that .txt file to a table in SQL Server with another button click event. Please help, thanks!

```
        private void butn_Upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
        fileDialog.Filter = "Textfiles|* .txt|All Files|*.*";
        fileDialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        Nullable<bool> dialogOK = fileDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (dialogOK == true)
        {
            string sFilenames = "";

            foreach (string sFilename in fileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                sFilenames += ";" + sFilename;
            }
            sFilenames = sFilenames.Substring(1);

            // Show file path in TextBox
            TbxFiles.Text = sFilenames;
        }
    }
```

This code is my second click event, which I would like to instert the .txtfile into SQL Server.

```
        private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        //I'm not sure how to take txt file and use it with an Update SQL Statement


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("");
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Data updated!");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }


enter code here
```

Comment: "insert the text file" can mean different things to different people. Is this an ETL style function where you read the file line-by-line and insert each line into a table? Do you insert a single row for each file containing the contents of the file? Something else?

Comment: And don't develop bad habits - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: And one last comment. The message "Data updated!" is misleading and can be confusing. And IMO no one needs such a "success" message anyways - that will be obvious since your GUI should refresh itself and make it obvious.

Comment: @SMor - I just grabbed one of the SQL commands to show as an example but I will be sure to remove it. But yes I am looking for an ETL style function. I was hoping to have something where I can delete the first 3 rows and then insert the t.xt file line-by-line